# React Warning eliminate Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React Warning eliminate Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I would like to eliminate the
「Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.」

The code is as follows

```
import { useState } from "react";

const SIZE_ARRAY = [
  {
    label: "Small",
    value: "sm"
  },
  {
    label: "Medium",
    value: "md"
  },
  {
    label: "Large",
    value: "lg"
  }
];

const DEVICE_ARRAY = [
  {
    deviceLabel: "PC",
    deviceValue: "pc"
  },
  {
    deviceLabel: "Tablet",
    deviceValue: "tablet"
  },
  {
    deviceLabel: "Mobile",
    deviceValue: "mobile"
  }
];

export default function SampleLoop() {
  const [option, setOption] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {SIZE_ARRAY.map((size) => {
          const { label, value } = size;
          return (
            <li key={label}>
              <span>Margin : {label}</span>
              {DEVICE_ARRAY.map((device) => {
                const { deviceLabel, deviceValue } = device;
                return (
                  <>
                    <input
                      key={deviceLabel}
                      onChange={(newValue) => {
                        setOption({
                          ...option,
                          margin_size: {
                            ...option.margin_size,
                            [value]: {
                              ...option.margin_size[value],
                              [deviceValue]: newValue
                            }
                          }
                        });
                      }}
                    />
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-mendel-98b310?file=/src/App.js)

It is a nested form of two loops.

Is there a different position to attach the KEY?

Comment: You need to put the key on the `<>` which is the outermost element in the output. If necessary, rename it to `Fragment` so you get `<React.Fragment key={XXX}>`. However, you don't need this element so removing it is even simpler and then the key will be on the outermost element.

Comment: Remove the redundant fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the redundant [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) around `<input>`

```
import { useState } from "react";

const SIZE_ARRAY = [
  {
    label: "Small",
    value: "sm"
  },
  {
    label: "Medium",
    value: "md"
  },
  {
    label: "Large",
    value: "lg"
  }
];

const DEVICE_ARRAY = [
  {
    deviceLabel: "PC",
    deviceValue: "pc"
  },
  {
    deviceLabel: "Tablet",
    deviceValue: "tablet"
  },
  {
    deviceLabel: "Mobile",
    deviceValue: "mobile"
  }
];

export default function SampleLoop() {
  const [option, setOption] = useState();

  return (
    <ul>
      {SIZE_ARRAY.map((size) => {
        const { label, value } = size;
        return (
          <li key={label}>
            <span>Margin : {label}</span>
            {DEVICE_ARRAY.map((device) => {
              const { deviceLabel, deviceValue } = device;
              return (
                <input
                  key={deviceLabel}
                  onChange={(newValue) => {
                    setOption({
                      ...option,
                      margin_size: {
                        ...option.margin_size,
                        [value]: {
                          ...option.margin_size[value],
                          [deviceValue]: newValue
                        }
                      }
                    });
                  }}
                />
              );
            })}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dank-flower-u0pch0]

Answer (score 2):

In here:

```
{DEVICE_ARRAY.map((device) => {
  const { deviceLabel, deviceValue } = device;
  return (
    <>
      <input
        key={deviceLabel}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setOption({
            ...option,
            margin_size: {
              ...option.margin_size,
              [value]: {
                ...option.margin_size[value],
                [deviceValue]: newValue
              }
            }
          });
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
})}
```

The "root element" of each child is the `</>`, i.e. `<Fragment/>`, not `<input/>`. So you should define the key in the former instead. Although quite frankly, you don't need that `Fragment` here unless you omitted some components in your posted code.

BTW, you can't use the fragment shorthand if you specify any props in it.
i.e. this doesn't work:

```
< key={deviceLabel}>
</>
```

Instead, do this

```
<Fragment key={deviceLabel}>
</Fragment>
```